# Asp.Net Pass value to Modal TextBox from GridView on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

As stated above, I wanted to know how could I possibly send data from gridview to modal Asp:TextBox

**GridView Button**

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<ItemTemplate>
      <a data-id="<%#Eval("BookFile") %>"  title="Add this item" class="openDialog">Open Modal</a>
</center>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".openDialog").click(function () {
            $('#Id').val($(this).data('id'));
            $("#addDialog").modal("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Modal**

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="addDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

       <!-- Modal Head -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModal1">Modal title</h5>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="bookId1" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Username</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Id" CssClass="form-control"/>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Id"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The field is required." />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!--End tag of Modal Body -->

      <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Add User" CssClass="btn btn-Success" />
      </div>


  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Whenever I use this, no data is populated to the textbox but whenever I use the input box the code works

```
<input type="text" name="Id" id="Id">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was able to solve this by simply changing the script from

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".openDialog").click(function () {
            $('#Id').val($(this).data('id'));
            $("#addDialog").modal("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".openDialog").click(function () {
             document.getElementById("<%=Id.ClientID%>").value = $(this).data('id');
            $("#addDialog").modal("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to answer this one, but we have future newbies.
You can do this Html button and a JavaScript code, here is a snippet.

Gridview Code

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="13%" HeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-Width="13%">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateModel" class="btn btn-default source" style="width:100%"  type="button" onclick="showUpdateModel('<%#Eval("ID")%>' , '<%#Eval("Name")%>', '<%#Eval("DOB")%>','<%#Eval("Class")%>','<%#Eval("Section")%>')">Edit</button>                         
       <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteModel" type="button" class="btn btn-default source" style="width:100%" onclick="showDelModel('<%#Eval("FeeRecID")%>')">Delete</button>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Above button will target the model to open, and onclick function will pass the values to modal fields.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showUpdateModel(id, name, dob, cls, sec) {

            if (id.length > 0) {

                $("[id*=txtID]").text(id);
                $("[id*=txtID]").val(id);
                $("[id*=txtName]").text(name);
                $("[id*=txtName]").val(name);
                $("[id*=txtDOB]").text(dob);
                $("[id*=txtDOB]").val(dob);
                $("[id*=txtClass]").text(cls);
                $("[id*=txtClass]").val(cls);
                $("[id*=txtSec]").text(sec);
                $("[id*=txtSec]").val(sec);                
            }
        }
    </script>
```